# Is SQLITE able to do this?

Tags: sqlite

Can this be done in SQLITE?

Extract the variable length text from 1 column between 2 know points,
and insert it into a different column between 2 different know points.
Both columns are VARCHAR.

At first I thought this would be pretty basic, but I am a relative beginner
and have spent days so far researching and trying to accomplish this task
but always keep wondering if it's an SQLITE restriction.

I can get part of it to work, but not all of it.

The first part seems to work, but I don't know how to save the contents of
subtitle for the next step.

```
-- strip SubTitle from FileName
SELECT
  filename,
  SUBSTR(filename, INSTR(filename, 'C\')+2, INSTR(filename, '] ') - INSTR(filename, ') ')-2) AS                       subtitle
FROM my_table where oid = 4040;
```

This part I know doesn't work, so be kind :)

```
-- insert into SubTitle 
UPDATE my_table
      SET event_details = replace(event_details, '<SubTitle>', subtitle)
 Where oid = 4040;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could use (i.e. the SELECT is embedded as an expression within the UPDATE):-

```
UPDATE my_table 
    SET event_details = replace(event_details, '<SubTitle>', SUBSTR(filename, INSTR(filename, 'C\')+2, INSTR(filename, '] ') - INSTR(filename, ') ')-2)) 
    WHERE oid = 4040
;
```

Comment: The only problem is I wanted to keep '<SubTitle>' as part of the replacement.

Comment: OK, I figured out how to add the <SubTitle> back in.